# Struts 2 datetimepicker defaults to 31/12/1969

Tags: struts2

I face 2 issues while using struts 2 datetimepicker. 
1. The value in datetimepicker field does not persist when the page is refreshed or when we click the back button from the next page
2. When an invalid date is entered in the field, the value defaults to 31/12/1969 or the previously selected date when the field loses focus.

Is there a way to overcome these?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us the relevant parts of the code you're using, so we can see the problem.  Note that 31 December 1969 (actually midnight UTC on 1 January 1970) is time 0 in Java(Script) and many other systems influenced by UNIX.